# WebMatrix - Create controller for CSHTML page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webmatrix

I'm working on a website with WebMatrix. I recently asked a question about fetching data from a database. When I had tried writing the data logic within my CSHTML page, I was quickly told that I was in the wrong to do that because I was contradicting the principals of MVC. The problem is, MVC was easy for me in Visual Studio 2010, where I had a view `page.aspx` and a controller `page.aspx.cs` for each page, but in WebMatrix, I am using the Razor C# syntax, so my pages are only a single `page.cshtml` file. When I create a new site or a new file, there is no MVC template, so I have to create the views and controllers myself.

How can I display data in `page.cshtml` that is fetched from the database using a controller (would my controller be 'page.cshtml.cs'?)? In other words, how can I separate a pages data logic from its actual content/markup/view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing ASP.NET MVC with WebMatrix WebPages. You are using only WebPages where all the code is inside Razor templates. There are no notions of controllers.

But even in WebMatrix you could separate your data access code in a separate file. Create a special folder called `~/App_Code` and inside this folder you could create .NET classes. For example you could have a `DataAccess.cs` file where you could put your data access logic. You could also reference external assemblies that you have created. For example:

```
@using MyNamespace

@{
    DataAccess myClass = new DataAccess();
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but the people who commented on my question crucified me for bad MVC usage and even though I was sure I wasn't even using MVC it convinced me otherwise.

Comment: Either those people don't know the difference between ASP.NET MVC and WebMatrix WebPages or you failed to explain that in your question or didn't use appropriate tags (just like in this question by the way - you have used the `asp.net-mvc` tag which has nothing to do with your question). Either way now you know the difference.

Comment: I used 'WebMatrix' and 'Razor' in my tags. I failed to get anything more than condescending remarks about how I must not know how MVC works. Anyways, thank you for the clarification. Also, if I made a function called `MyFunc()` in `DataAccess.cs`, would I be able to call that from any page? And would `MyFunc()` be able to output HTML? Or is markup not allowed in a C# file?

Comment: First, you cannot declare functions inside a C# file. You declare classes and those classes could contain functions. If you have defined a class in your C# file you could invoke it from your Razor page. But you cannot return markup, that's not what C# is supposed to do. You should only return models and other classes and inside your Razor page based on the result of this function call build the markup.

Comment: Yeah after playing with it I figured that out, which is what I should have done in the first place.